# Why exactly is π(mean of radius)² less than the mean of the areas calculated for each radius?

Tags: geometry, circles

For example, a uniformly distributed value for a radius between 0 and 1 is calculated many times and the area for each radius is calculated:

```
μ(radius) = 0.4998

μ(area) = 1.0467

π ( μ(radius) ) ² = 0.7849
```

If you compare the mean of the areas calculated during the loop with the value of the mean of the radii squared, why are they different? I would guess that it's to do with squaring the radius each time having a logarithmic / exponential effect on the sum of the areas, but I have no idea how. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general $E(X^2)\ne E(X)^2$. The simplest case to see this is when $X=\pm1$ with probability $\frac12$ each, so that $E(X)=0\ne E(X^2)=1$.
In fact, $$V(X):=E((X-E(X))^2)=E(X^2-2E(X)X+E(X)^2) = E(X^2)-E(X)^2$$ is the variance of random variable $X$.

Since the variance oof the [uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29) on $[0,1]$ is $\frac1{12}$, we'd expect the difference between your expressions to be $\frac\pi{12}\approx 0.2618$, which matches very well with your numerical results.

Answer (score 1):

Because

$$E(r^2) \ge E(r)^2$$

where $E(X)$ is the mean of the quantity $X$.  This is true because of something called [Schwartz's Inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchwarzsInequality.html).  That is,

$$\left |\int_0^R dr \, r \right |^2 \le \int_0^R dr \, r^2$$

Answer (score 1):

If $A=\pi\cdot R^2$ and $R$ is not almost surely constant, then $\mathbb E(A)=\pi\cdot\mathbb E(R^2)\gt\pi\cdot(\mathbb E R)^2$ by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.